# 500 Internal Server Error when submitted a nested form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, internal-server-error

I get a 500 Internal Server Error when I submit the nested form which has two models - Member and ChildrenInformation.

**Error:**

> 500 Internal Server Error
>
> If you are the administrator of this website, then please read this web application's log file and/or the web server's log file to find out what went wrong.

I checked the log file, and this is what I found out:

> TypeError (expected Hash (got Array) for param `child_info_attrib'):

Here are the other parts of my rails project 
 
**View (new.html.erb>**

```
  <%= form_for(@member) do |f| %>
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :gender, "Gender" %><br />
    <%= f.select :gender, options_for_select(["Male", "Female"]) %>
  </div>
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :fname, "First Name" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :age, "Age" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :age %>
  </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :membership_id, "Membership ID" %>
    <%= f.text_field :membership_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Branch" %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:branch_id, Branch.all, :id, :name) %>
  </div>
  <% for children_information in @member.children_informations %>
     <%= fields_for "member[child_info_attrib][]", children_information do |children_info_form| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= children_info_form.label :name, "Name" %><br />
        <%= children_info_form.text_field :name %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= children_info_form.label :gender, "Gender" %><br />
        <%= children_info_form.select :gender, options_for_select(["Male", "Female"]) %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= children_info_form.label :birthdate, "Birthdate" %><br />
     nn <%= children_info_form.datetime_select :birthdate, :discard_hour => true, 
:order => [:month, :day, :year], :start_year => 1900 %>
        </div>
   </div>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>`
```

**Model (Member)**

```
 class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :children_informations
    
    def child_info_attrib=(attribs)
        attribs.each do |attrib|
          children_informations.build(attrib)
        end
    end 
 end
```

**Model (ChildrenInformation)**

```
class ChildrenInformation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :member
end
```

**Controller (MembersController)**

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController
def new
    @member = Member.new
    @member.children_informations.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @member }
    end
  end
def create
    @member = Member.new(params[:member])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @member.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@member, :notice => 'Member was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @member, :status => :created, :location => @member }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @member.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**Development Log:**  http://pastebin.com/n9E2nyFv (members table has a lot of fields) 
 
What I tried so far is to omit the nested form, and it did work. 
Additionally, I based this way of using nested form through RailsCasts (http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1). 
 
How can I submit it successfully with the nested form?

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mistake that I defaced the note of RailsCasts episode about nested forms (http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1) that it is outdated, and I should instead follow the latest episode of the said topic (http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1). It worked now :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you're building your nested form incorrectly:

```
#app/views/members/new.html.erb
 <% for children_information in @member.children_informations %>
     <%= fields_for "member[child_info_attrib][]", children_information do |children_info_form| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= children_info_form.label :name, "Name" %><br />
        <%= children_info_form.text_field :name %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= children_info_form.label :gender, "Gender" %><br />
        <%= children_info_form.select :gender, options_for_select(["Male", "Female"]) %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= children_info_form.label :birthdate, "Birthdate" %><br />
     nn <%= children_info_form.datetime_select :birthdate, :discard_hour => true, 
:order => [:month, :day, :year], :start_year => 1900 %>
        </div>
   </div>
       <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

You'd need to do this:

**View**

```
<%= f.fields_for :children_informations do |children_info_form| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= children_info_form.label :name, "Name" %><br />
        <%= children_info_form.text_field :name %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= children_info_form.label :gender, "Gender" %><br />
        <%= children_info_form.select :gender, options_for_select(["Male", "Female"]) %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= children_info_form.label :birthdate, "Birthdate" %><br />
     nn <%= children_info_form.datetime_select :birthdate, :discard_hour => true, 
:order => [:month, :day, :year], :start_year => 1900 %>
        </div>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

This will create the form elements with the correct data, but I also think your handling of the data can be improved. As you're on Rails 3, I'll wait for a comment to see if you'd like me to write some code for it!

Comment: Hi @rich peck. I tried your answer, and it did submit the form successfully. But when I checked on the database, the fields are all NULL but there are record entries.

Comment: That means we're not handling them properly when they go to the model - do you have the log of the passed params available?

Comment: How can I retrieve the params?

Comment: If you go into `root_dir/log` and open the developer log

Comment: It should have the requests - you'll have to find the latest one where you've submitted your form - we'll have a look and see what we can do

Comment: The members table has several fields, but I filled them all in the form. I noticed a warning that said, "Can't mass-assign" protected attributes". Here's the log: http://pastebin.com/n9E2nyFv

Comment: Let me check and get back to you in a second!

Comment: @hi rich peck. how was the log?

Comment: @hi rich, thanks for your time. it worked now. i just followed the updated railscast about nested forms.

Answer (score 1):

the railscast episode you are following is dated 2007.
I don't think this approach is the best in doing nested forms.

this

> ```
> def child_info_attrib=(attribs)
>     attribs.each do |attrib|
>       children_informations.build(attrib)
>     end
> end
> ```

could be simplified to this (if you are using rails 3.x >)

> attr_accessible :childs_attributes
>   accepts_nested_attributes_for :childs

If you want references or some tutorials to follow I would recommend 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised
http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

or if you don't those, you could look at this gem
https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon
which simplifies what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: hi @rav thanks for that :) that was quite a reminder to use the updated railscast.